# What is the origin of the specified term in a standard proof that the limit of a product is the product of the limits?

Tags: limits

I’m looking over a [standard proof](https://planetmath.org/proofoflimitruleofproduct) that the limit of a product is the product of the limits. I see where most of the terms come from, but there’s a $1$ whose origin I don’t understand. Could someone explain why the proof has $(1 + |F|)$ in the second term instead of $|F|$ by itself?

[image: red box term]

Comment: It's not necessary. I suspect it's to give the "clean" $=\varepsilon$ in the last line instead of $<\varepsilon$.

Comment: The reason is that $\lvert F \rvert$ may be zero, and they need something definitely nonzero in the denominator.  So they chose to pick something that's guaranteed to be larger than $\lvert F \rvert$, namely $1 + \lvert F \rvert$.

Comment: @L.F. The question isn't about the $1+|F|$ in the denominator. It's only about the part in the red square with the question mark.

Comment: @user469053 What if $F=0$ or $G=0?$ We have to choose some positive value, but yes, the specific value chosen depend makes it work out nicely.

Comment: @user469053 The reason why they picked the $1 + \lvert F \rvert$ in the red square is because they picked $1 + \lvert F \rvert$ in the denominator.  I assumed this was obvious.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The question is not about the $1+$ in the denominators. It is only about the part in the red box with the arrow and the question mark. It is clear from the picture that OP understands the denominators. The condition $|F|=0$ does not require the $1+$ that OP has indicated with the box and question mark.

Comment: If you commenters would read more carefully, OP clearly understands where the portions in the yellow, blue, and green boxes are coming from. The question is not about the $1+$ in the denominators. All comments of the form "we need a non-zero denominator" are answering questions that OP is not asking. OP very clearly indicated the exact portion of the inequality they need help understanding with a red box, an arrow, **and** a question mark.

Comment: @L.F. I know why they picked the $1+$ in the red square. I already said why in a previous comment.

Comment: @user469053 After reading your explanation, I think your interpretation of the OP's confusion is possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @user469053 But does the OP really understand *why* we divide by $1+|F|$ in the first step, rather than understanding *why* it is a legal thing we can do? Those are different notions of "why."

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I indeed understand the basic notion of canceling the $1+|F|$, but that just raises the question of why that denominator was chosen in the first place. (Though a standard practice, I feel that this use of “magic” epsilon values is a bad one since it only makes sense if you’ve already done the proof.) The answer, per L. F.’s comment, is to handle the case $|F| = 0$. As I noted in another comment, this is exactly the sort of detail that I believe should be mentioned explicitly in the proof, since leaving it implicit risks confusion (e.g., mine).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are free to ask OP if they understand the denominator. In fact, it's probably good practice to do so. But to answer a question OP didn't ask **instead of** answering the question they did ask **because you didn't read the question carefully** and then attempting to provide a post hoc justification is another matter. All of the answers/comments I saw about the denominator **did not** address the question OP **actually** asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the inequality in the given proof is valid because $|F| < 1 + |F|$, which then cancels the $1 + |F|$ in the denominator. But the spirit of the original question was “Why did the proof make this particular choice of inequality?” In other words, why was $1 + |F|$ chosen to appear in the denominator in the first place?

The origin of that term is a common convention of picking initial values to arrange for the answer at the end to be exactly $\varepsilon$. (This is potentially confusing since it effectively requires you to have already done the proof, at least in your head.) Seen from this perspective, the original question then reduces to asking why we don’t write this:

$$
|g(x) - G| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2|F|}
$$
and then use this inequality:
$$
|f(x)g(x) - FG| < (1 + |G|)\frac{\varepsilon}{2(1 + |G|)} + |F| \frac{\varepsilon}{2|F|}.
$$

As noted by one of the commenters, the answer is that this doesn’t work when $|F| = 0$. We could simply handle this case separately, but choosing the initial value
$$
|g(x) - G| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1 + |F|)}
$$
conveniently allows us to handle all values of $|F|$ at once. Because $|F| < 1 + |F|$, the second inequality in
\begin{align*} 
|f(x)g(x) - FG| & < (1 + |G|)\frac{\varepsilon}{2(1 + |G|} + |F| \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1 + |F|)} \\
 & < (1 + |G|)\frac{\varepsilon}{2(1 + |G|)} + (1 + |F|) \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1 + |F|)} 
\end{align*}
holds and we get the original proof.

One possible clarification to the proof would thus be to note that the term $1 + |F|$ is chosen to handle the case $|F| = 0$, while also noting the use of the inequality $|F| < 1 + |F|$. (Perhaps these considerations were considered “too obvious” to include, but they weren’t obvious to me, and I believe I am part of the intended audience for the proof. This suggests that including such details might not be such a bad idea after all.)

Answer (score 1):

$|F| < (1+|F|)$. The inequality still holds so the proof still holds. They use $(1+|F|)$ instead of $|F|$ to cancel the denominator.

Comment: Thanks. That just raises the question of why $1 + |F|$ appears in the denominator, though. It appears that the answer, per L. F.’s comment on a different answer, is to handle the case $|F| = 0$. In my view, this is exactly the sort of detail that should be mentioned explicitly in the proof since leaving it implicit risks confusion (e.g., mine).

Comment: Sorry, that's a different question than the one you originally asked. It seems you've answered it yourself though!

Comment: In an important sense it’s the same question as the original since the spirit of the question was “Why did the proof make this particular choice of inequality?” The cancellation was the proximate but not the ultimate reason, which is why I kept pulling on the loose thread. Your answer was a critical part of unraveling the answer, though, so thanks for the contribution!